# Proof: A $\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ A Jordan measurable and J(A)=0 iff c(A)=0

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been given the aforementioned proof but I have been having a hard time since I am not entirely sure the statement is true. However here is my attempt at a solution, excuse my lack of formalism

A couple notes c(A) means content zero NOT the Lebesgue measure zero, $X_{A}$ is the characteristic function
$ =$
$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 if x \in A
\\ 
0 if x \notin A 
\end{matrix}\right. $

[image: Páez Cárdenas, Cálculo multivariable.]

> Translation: Definition. Given $\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ bounded we say
> that A is **Jordan-measurable** if the characteristic function of A is
> integrable over some rectangle R that contains A. Given that we say
> that the Jordan measure of a (denoted J(A)) is given by [integral]

Proof:

*Hypothesis A $\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is jordan measurable*  $\implies$ A is bounded.

Then for R a closed rectangle s.t A $\subset$ R $ \int_{R}X_{A}$ exists and $\int_{R} X_{A}=0$ .

$\int_{R} X_{A} $ exists $ \implies \int_{R}^{-} X_{A}$ and $\int_{- R}X_{A} $ exist and they equal zero.

Let P be a partition of R and Ri's the induced subrectangles, then by definition of lower integral,

$\int_{-R} X_{A}= sup[L(x_{A},P)] = sup[\sum_{Ri} (mi \cdot c(Ri))]$

Where mi = inf(X_{A}(y)| y $\in$ Ri). Since we are talking about $X_{A}$ we have that:

i) $R_{i} \bigcap  A = \emptyset \implies $  mi=0

ii) $R_{i} \bigcap  A \neq \emptyset \land R_{i} \bigcap  A^{c} \neq \emptyset \implies $ mi=0.

iii) $R_{i} \bigcap  A \neq \emptyset \land R_{i} \bigcap  A^{c} = \emptyset \implies $ mi=1

Note 1: iii) is equivalent to $Ri \subset A$ and is the only case that adds any value to the sum

Then
$0 = \int_{- R} X_{A}= sup(L(x_{A},P)) = sup(\sum_{Ri \subset A} [1 \cdot c(Ri))] = sup[\sum_{Ri \subset A} (c(Ri))] $

$\implies \sum_{Ri \subset A} (c(Ri)) \leq 0$

But c(Ri) $\geq 0 \forall Ri \implies \sum_{Ri \subset A} (c(Ri)) \geq 0 $

$\therefore \sum_{Ri \subset A} (c(Ri)) = 0 $

I believe this could lead me to prove that int(A)=$\emptyset$ and I know J(A)>0 if int(A)$\neq \emptyset$

EDIT:
Now

$\int_{R}^{-} X_{A}= inf[U(x_{A},P)] = inf[\sum_{Ri} (Mi \cdot c(Ri))]$

Where Mi = sup(X_{A}(y)| y $\in$ Ri) Since we are talking about $X_{A}$ we have that:

i) $R_{i} \bigcap  A = \emptyset \implies $  Mi=0

ii) $R_{i} \bigcap  A \neq \emptyset \land  R_{i} \bigcap  A^{c} = \emptyset  \implies $ Mi=1

iii) $R_{i} \bigcap  A \neq \emptyset \land R_{i} \bigcap  A^{c} \neq \emptyset \implies $ Mi=1.

Note 2: The union of ii) and iii) can be described equivalently as $R_{i} \bigcap  A \neq \emptyset $.

ii) is equivalent to $Ri \bigcap \delta A \neq 0$

iii) is equivalent to $Ri \subset A$

Then, by note 2:

$0 = \int_{R}^{-} X_{A}= inf[U(x_{A},P)] = inf[\sum_{Ri} (Mi \cdot c(Ri))]$

$\implies inf[\sum_{Ri} (Mi \cdot $ c(Ri))] = inf[$ \sum_{Ri \bigcap \delta A \neq 0} (c(Ri)) $ + $\sum_{Ri \subset A} (c(Ri))$]

but, from our previous result $\sum_{Ri \subset A} (c(Ri)) = 0$

$\implies 0 = inf[\sum_{Ri \bigcap \delta A \neq 0} (c(Ri)) $]

since c(Ri) $\geq 0 \forall Ri \implies c(Ri)=0 \forall Ri\bigcap \delta A \neq 0 $

$\implies \sum_{Ri \bigcap A \neq 0} (c(Ri)) = 0$

Now let's call R' the set of Ri's s.t $Ri \bigcap A \neq 0$

Then A $\in \cup_{j}R'_{j}$
(The set of $R'_{j}$ are finite since they come from a partition)

and $\sum_{j} c(R'_{j}) = 0 \therefore \forall \epsilon > 0 \sum_{j} c(R'_{j}) < \epsilon $

$\implies c(A)=0$

Comment: A mi me cuesta, seguir el hilo de su argumento .Quizá [esto](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/jordan-content-and-boundaries/) le pueda servir de algo

Comment: He corregido todo dado que estaba completamente mal pues escribí integrales superiores en lugar de inferiores, creo que tengo una idea de como utilizar el refinamiento, lo intentaré y pronto lo subiré si me lleva a algo.

Comment: Sale, pues. Espero su aportación. En la liga que le mandé verá como pasar la definición suya, (osea la de las integrales), a una equivalente, más facil de aplicar. Bueno, a mi juicio, sale más facil.  Pd: Sería conveniente aprender a usar [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/), así no batallamos tanto por entender los argumentos!